# Laravel 5 access session user

Tags: laravel-5

When a user is logged in and I dd the user I get an all the properties of the current user on screen.

```
$testing = $request->user();

dd($testing);
```

The user object:

```
User {#596 ▼
  #table: "users"
  +primaryKey: "id"
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▶]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
}
```

How can I access for example the `#attributes` array from the controller if I want to use any attribute to run user checks in the controller methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the attributes the following way:

[magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) `__get()`:

```
$request->user()->yourAttribute;
```

or call the `getAttribute` method directly:

```
$request->user()->getAttribute('yourAttribute');
```